# Access my Documents folder on another PC in my Home Group

Tags: windows, home-networking

I have a laptop and a desktop in my HomeGroup, and both machines run Windows 10. I log into both devices with my outlook.com account.

I can use Remote Desktop to access the desktop from the laptop.
However, sometimes I just want to access a file on the desktop from the laptop, so RDP seems like overkill (and I dislike window management with an RDP session).
In File Explorer, I can see the desktop, but only the public folder.

How do I share my Documents folder across the HomeGroup? I know that I could use OneDrive to synchronize the two machines, but in this case, I do not want to use OneDrive (a combination of large files and files that are under version control).

Comment: This would require you change the permissions on the User profile, and then share that directory, but **I do not recommend you do that.**  The only safe way to do what you want It sounds like you should use the Public profile to remotely share files

Comment: @ramhound ok, thanks. I will go the public folder route.